# wp_insert_post creates multiple pages

Tags: wp-insert-post

I have a function in functions.php which automatically generates a page. It doesn't check to see if there is already a page with the same title at the moment.

The function is started with:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_pages' );
```

**edit**: I only want this to run **once** every page load. 
I think it is the same thing if I would use

`add_action( 'init', 'add_pages' );`

Here is the code in the add pages function:

```
function add_pages() {

    $content = "text content";

    $page = array(
        'post_title' => 'A unique title?',
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => 0 
    );


    // Add page
    $insert_id = wp_insert_post( $page );
}
```

When I reload the "posts" page in wordpress admin, two new pages are created. When I reload again, four new pages are created. When I reload again, a whole 
bunch of pages are created. I was wondering if there is an explanation for this?

**edit:** If I change the **post_title** and reload, only one page is created. But if I reload again, two pages are created. But after that, it behaves irrationally, sometimes there are consistently two pages created on each page load , but sometimes a large number of pages are created.

I intend to check if the page title already exists, but I wanted to understand this behaviour anyway.

Comment: `This hook is called during each page load`. You probably want some other hook. Anyway, it should still add 1 on each load only huh? Does your console throw any errors?

Answer (score 3):

`after_setup_theme` is not the hook you are looking for - you want [`after_switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme) - this hook will only run once, when your theme is initally activated.

Comment: I actually want it to be like this - the function should start when a page loads. I can remove the code when I'm done. I'm testing things right now. If I use "after_switch_theme" , nothing happens until I switch theme (I guess), and only once as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code, it will not create page if title already exists:

```
function add_pages() {
    $content = "text content";
    $postTitle = 'A unique title?';
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . '
            WHERE post_title = %s
            AND post_type = \'page\'',
        $postTitle
    );
    $wpdb->query( $query );

    if ( $wpdb->num_rows ) {
        // Title already exists
    } else {
        $page = array(
            'post_title'   => 'A unique title?',
            'post_content' => $content,
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_author'  => 1,
            'post_type'    => 'page',
            'post_parent'  => 0 
        );

        // Add page
        $insert_id = wp_insert_post( $page );
    }
}
```