# wp_insert_posts keeps adding multiple pages

Tags: functions, pages

I have a function that creates a page but I only want one page and the code below keeps adding multiple pages (2 at a time). Is there a way to only add one post? I tired [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212727/wp-insert-post-creates-multiple-pages) but it didn't work.

```
$my_post  = array( 
               'post_title'     => 'My page Reql',
               'post_type'      => 'page',
               'post_name'      => 'archive',
               'post_content'   => 'This is my page reql.',
               'post_status'    => 'publish',
               'comment_status' => 'closed',
               'ping_status'    => 'closed',
               'post_author'    => 1,
               'menu_order'     => 0,
               'guid'           => site_url() . '/archive' );
$PageID = wp_insert_post( $my_post, FALSE ); // Get Post ID - FALSE to return 0 instead of wp_error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the page exists or not, and create it only if it doesn't already exist. [`get_page_by_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) can help you in this case:

```
// Check if the page already exists
if( ! get_page_by_title('My page Reql') ) {
    // The page doesn't exist, so let's create it
}
```

Also, you might want to investigate how are you calling the function. You might be calling it twice, that might be the reason it's creating a copy of each post.